# Bootstrap : Table responsive overflow-x scroll from 1200px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a bootstrap table. When I resize my browser below 1200 ,there should be overflow-x:scroll;
Here is the code I have tried.

```css
svg{
width:14px;
}

td{
font-size:16px;
}

@media (max-width:1200px){
.table-responsive{
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table b-t b-b no-footer">
                        <thead class="bg-white">
                            <tr class="font-bold no_border font_size_12">
                                <th class="sorting no_border" >
                                  <div class="pull-left table_data_checkbox">
                                    <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                      <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <i></i>
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>Table head 1</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 2</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 3</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 4</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 5</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 6</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 7</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 8</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 9</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="odd cursor_pointer" >
                            <td valign="middle" >
                              <div class="table_data_checkbox">
                                  <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                    <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                      <input type="checkbox">
                                      <i></i>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 1</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 2</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 3</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 4</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 5</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 6</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 7</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 8</td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="particular_record_action_selection_div">
                                <span>
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M21.459,5.761l7.02,7.056L10.709,30.68l-7.016-7.056L21.459,5.761z M33.805,4.058l-3.13-3.147
                                     c-1.21-1.215-3.176-1.215-4.389,0l-3,3.016l7.021,7.056l3.498-3.516C34.744,6.523,34.744,5.001,33.805,4.058z M0.02,33.542
                                     c-0.127,0.578,0.391,1.095,0.965,0.955l7.822-1.907l-7.015-7.056L0.02,33.542z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M26.663,7.373l-1.677,2.133c3.614,2.785,5.417,7.293,4.706,11.766
                                     c-0.521,3.283-2.303,6.167-5.015,8.125c-2.714,1.956-6.033,2.75-9.348,2.232c-6.844-1.067-11.536-7.448-10.46-14.225
                                     c0.521-3.284,2.303-6.169,5.015-8.126c2.369-1.708,5.201-2.527,8.087-2.365l-2.36,2.452l1.75,1.653l3.725-3.872v0.001l1.668-1.735
                                     l-1.749-1.652h-0.001l-3.908-3.689l-1.67,1.735l2.546,2.403c-3.461-0.163-6.852,0.834-9.694,2.883
                                     c-3.303,2.382-5.471,5.895-6.105,9.891c-1.31,8.249,4.4,16.017,12.731,17.314c0.805,0.125,1.609,0.188,2.409,0.188
                                     c3.209,0,6.326-0.998,8.968-2.906c3.304-2.38,5.472-5.893,6.105-9.889C33.253,16.248,31.06,10.761,26.663,7.373z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063v-1.555c1.862-0.207,3.675-1.372,3.675-3.583
                                     c0-3.005-2.822-3.35-4.883-3.601c-1.318-0.157-2.327-0.337-2.327-1.128c0-1.099,1.565-1.217,2.238-1.217
                                     c0.998,0,2.063,0.465,2.425,1.058l0.106,0.173l2.069-0.948l-0.102-0.207c-0.771-1.562-2.154-2.014-3.202-2.195v-1.371h-2.425v1.364
                                     c-2.256,0.329-3.595,1.57-3.595,3.344c0,2.894,2.653,3.187,4.587,3.402c1.725,0.201,2.528,0.623,2.528,1.327
                                     c0,1.343-1.878,1.448-2.455,1.448c-1.282,0-2.518-0.634-2.875-1.474l-0.088-0.208l-2.25,0.944l0.091,0.208
                                     c0.665,1.543,2.102,2.51,4.058,2.74v1.479H18.778z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;" >
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M4.973,8.047c0,0,0.923,0.875,0.923,1.384v22.401c0,1.482,1.325,2.686,2.96,2.686h16.85
                                     c1.635,0,2.96-1.204,2.96-2.686V9.433c0-0.511,0.926-1.384,0.926-1.384V5.334H4.973V8.047z M22.121,11.148h2.201v17.296h-2.201
                                     V11.148z M16.228,11.148h2.195v17.296h-2.195V11.148z M10.919,11.148h2.198v17.296h-2.198V11.148z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M30.667,3.093h-6.823c-0.341-1.731-2.011-3.05-4.015-3.05h-5.091c-2.005,0-3.675,1.319-4.015,3.05
                                     H3.896V4.75h26.771V3.093z M13.007,3.093c0.28-0.613,0.951-1.045,1.728-1.045h5.093c0.778,0,1.446,0.435,1.729,1.045H13.007z"/>
                                  </svg>

                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
```

You can see in the browser and resize it , I want overflow-x:scroll when I resize my browser just below 1200px;

Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make the width fix as 1200px.
Below is the css code:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .table-responsive {
      overflow-x: scroll !important;
      width: 1200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: yep, this actually makes more sense than min-width. :) up-vote for you Rakesh.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is trying to stretch the content of the table to fit the screen. If you want to make it show the scroll, then you need to say that the table requires a minimum width **min-width: 1200px;**

Hope this helps. ;)

```css
svg{
width:14px;
}

td{
font-size:16px;
}

@media (max-width:1200px){
.table-responsive{
  min-width: 1200px; /* <-- ;) */
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table b-t b-b no-footer">
                        <thead class="bg-white">
                            <tr class="font-bold no_border font_size_12">
                                <th class="sorting no_border" >
                                  <div class="pull-left table_data_checkbox">
                                    <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                      <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <i></i>
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>Table head 1</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 2</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 3</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 4</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 5</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 6</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 7</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 8</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 9</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="odd cursor_pointer" >
                            <td valign="middle" >
                              <div class="table_data_checkbox">
                                  <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                    <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                      <input type="checkbox">
                                      <i></i>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 1</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 2</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 3</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 4</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 5</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 6</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 7</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 8</td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="particular_record_action_selection_div">
                                <span>
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M21.459,5.761l7.02,7.056L10.709,30.68l-7.016-7.056L21.459,5.761z M33.805,4.058l-3.13-3.147
                                     c-1.21-1.215-3.176-1.215-4.389,0l-3,3.016l7.021,7.056l3.498-3.516C34.744,6.523,34.744,5.001,33.805,4.058z M0.02,33.542
                                     c-0.127,0.578,0.391,1.095,0.965,0.955l7.822-1.907l-7.015-7.056L0.02,33.542z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M26.663,7.373l-1.677,2.133c3.614,2.785,5.417,7.293,4.706,11.766
                                     c-0.521,3.283-2.303,6.167-5.015,8.125c-2.714,1.956-6.033,2.75-9.348,2.232c-6.844-1.067-11.536-7.448-10.46-14.225
                                     c0.521-3.284,2.303-6.169,5.015-8.126c2.369-1.708,5.201-2.527,8.087-2.365l-2.36,2.452l1.75,1.653l3.725-3.872v0.001l1.668-1.735
                                     l-1.749-1.652h-0.001l-3.908-3.689l-1.67,1.735l2.546,2.403c-3.461-0.163-6.852,0.834-9.694,2.883
                                     c-3.303,2.382-5.471,5.895-6.105,9.891c-1.31,8.249,4.4,16.017,12.731,17.314c0.805,0.125,1.609,0.188,2.409,0.188
                                     c3.209,0,6.326-0.998,8.968-2.906c3.304-2.38,5.472-5.893,6.105-9.889C33.253,16.248,31.06,10.761,26.663,7.373z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063v-1.555c1.862-0.207,3.675-1.372,3.675-3.583
                                     c0-3.005-2.822-3.35-4.883-3.601c-1.318-0.157-2.327-0.337-2.327-1.128c0-1.099,1.565-1.217,2.238-1.217
                                     c0.998,0,2.063,0.465,2.425,1.058l0.106,0.173l2.069-0.948l-0.102-0.207c-0.771-1.562-2.154-2.014-3.202-2.195v-1.371h-2.425v1.364
                                     c-2.256,0.329-3.595,1.57-3.595,3.344c0,2.894,2.653,3.187,4.587,3.402c1.725,0.201,2.528,0.623,2.528,1.327
                                     c0,1.343-1.878,1.448-2.455,1.448c-1.282,0-2.518-0.634-2.875-1.474l-0.088-0.208l-2.25,0.944l0.091,0.208
                                     c0.665,1.543,2.102,2.51,4.058,2.74v1.479H18.778z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;" >
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M4.973,8.047c0,0,0.923,0.875,0.923,1.384v22.401c0,1.482,1.325,2.686,2.96,2.686h16.85
                                     c1.635,0,2.96-1.204,2.96-2.686V9.433c0-0.511,0.926-1.384,0.926-1.384V5.334H4.973V8.047z M22.121,11.148h2.201v17.296h-2.201
                                     V11.148z M16.228,11.148h2.195v17.296h-2.195V11.148z M10.919,11.148h2.198v17.296h-2.198V11.148z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M30.667,3.093h-6.823c-0.341-1.731-2.011-3.05-4.015-3.05h-5.091c-2.005,0-3.675,1.319-4.015,3.05
                                     H3.896V4.75h26.771V3.093z M13.007,3.093c0.28-0.613,0.951-1.045,1.728-1.045h5.093c0.778,0,1.446,0.435,1.729,1.045H13.007z"/>
                                  </svg>

                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following css gets trigger when we go below width 768px for table responsiveness `by default bootstrap behaviour`. All  you  need is to trigger this css below 1200px.**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){

.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th{white-space:nowrap;}
}
```

```css
svg{
width:14px;
}

td{
font-size:16px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){

.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th{white-space:nowrap;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table b-t b-b no-footer">
                        <thead class="bg-white">
                            <tr class="font-bold no_border font_size_12">
                                <th class="sorting no_border" >
                                  <div class="pull-left table_data_checkbox">
                                    <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                      <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <i></i>
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>Table head 1</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 2</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 3</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 4</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 5</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 6</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 7</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 8</th>
                                <th class="sorting no_border " >Table head 9</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="odd cursor_pointer" >
                            <td valign="middle" >
                              <div class="table_data_checkbox">
                                  <div class="checkbox v-middle m-t-none m-b-none ">
                                    <label class="i-checks i-checks-sm">
                                      <input type="checkbox">
                                      <i></i>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 1</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 2</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 3</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 4</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 5</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 6</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 7</td>
                            <td valign="middle">Table Data 8</td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="particular_record_action_selection_div">
                                <span>
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M21.459,5.761l7.02,7.056L10.709,30.68l-7.016-7.056L21.459,5.761z M33.805,4.058l-3.13-3.147
                                     c-1.21-1.215-3.176-1.215-4.389,0l-3,3.016l7.021,7.056l3.498-3.516C34.744,6.523,34.744,5.001,33.805,4.058z M0.02,33.542
                                     c-0.127,0.578,0.391,1.095,0.965,0.955l7.822-1.907l-7.015-7.056L0.02,33.542z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;">
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M26.663,7.373l-1.677,2.133c3.614,2.785,5.417,7.293,4.706,11.766
                                     c-0.521,3.283-2.303,6.167-5.015,8.125c-2.714,1.956-6.033,2.75-9.348,2.232c-6.844-1.067-11.536-7.448-10.46-14.225
                                     c0.521-3.284,2.303-6.169,5.015-8.126c2.369-1.708,5.201-2.527,8.087-2.365l-2.36,2.452l1.75,1.653l3.725-3.872v0.001l1.668-1.735
                                     l-1.749-1.652h-0.001l-3.908-3.689l-1.67,1.735l2.546,2.403c-3.461-0.163-6.852,0.834-9.694,2.883
                                     c-3.303,2.382-5.471,5.895-6.105,9.891c-1.31,8.249,4.4,16.017,12.731,17.314c0.805,0.125,1.609,0.188,2.409,0.188
                                     c3.209,0,6.326-0.998,8.968-2.906c3.304-2.38,5.472-5.893,6.105-9.889C33.253,16.248,31.06,10.761,26.663,7.373z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063L18.778,27.063v-1.555c1.862-0.207,3.675-1.372,3.675-3.583
                                     c0-3.005-2.822-3.35-4.883-3.601c-1.318-0.157-2.327-0.337-2.327-1.128c0-1.099,1.565-1.217,2.238-1.217
                                     c0.998,0,2.063,0.465,2.425,1.058l0.106,0.173l2.069-0.948l-0.102-0.207c-0.771-1.562-2.154-2.014-3.202-2.195v-1.371h-2.425v1.364
                                     c-2.256,0.329-3.595,1.57-3.595,3.344c0,2.894,2.653,3.187,4.587,3.402c1.725,0.201,2.528,0.623,2.528,1.327
                                     c0,1.343-1.878,1.448-2.455,1.448c-1.282,0-2.518-0.634-2.875-1.474l-0.088-0.208l-2.25,0.944l0.091,0.208
                                     c0.665,1.543,2.102,2.51,4.058,2.74v1.479H18.778z"/>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="m-l-sm">
                                  <svg viewBox="0 0 34.56 34.56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 34.56 34.56;" >
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M4.973,8.047c0,0,0.923,0.875,0.923,1.384v22.401c0,1.482,1.325,2.686,2.96,2.686h16.85
                                     c1.635,0,2.96-1.204,2.96-2.686V9.433c0-0.511,0.926-1.384,0.926-1.384V5.334H4.973V8.047z M22.121,11.148h2.201v17.296h-2.201
                                     V11.148z M16.228,11.148h2.195v17.296h-2.195V11.148z M10.919,11.148h2.198v17.296h-2.198V11.148z"/>
                                    <path style="fill:#59666E;" d="M30.667,3.093h-6.823c-0.341-1.731-2.011-3.05-4.015-3.05h-5.091c-2.005,0-3.675,1.319-4.015,3.05
                                     H3.896V4.75h26.771V3.093z M13.007,3.093c0.28-0.613,0.951-1.045,1.728-1.045h5.093c0.778,0,1.446,0.435,1.729,1.045H13.007z"/>
                                  </svg>

                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
```